# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = q < 1$ to show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

> If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = q <1$  and $a_n>0$ then $a_{n+1} = q * a_n$ and we see, that $a_{n+1} <a_n$ and sequence is monotonically decreasing. Because $a_n > 0$ and sequence is monotonically decreasing $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

My question is: is this argument enough for the proof? Or I need to be more rigorous. If yes, what should I add?

Comment: The argument needs to be more *true*, rather than more rigorous. Consider the decreasing sequence $1+\frac1n$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli so can you give me a hint?

Comment: You have only shown that $(a_n)$ converges, nothing more !

Comment: One way is arguing that there are constants $A>0$ and $\alpha<1$ such that eventually $a\le A\alpha^n$. Another one is using Fred's hint to show that the limit cannot be $>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $a_n =1+1/n,$ positive, decreasing and limit $=1.$

Not correct your conclusion.

Given:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }a_{n+1}/a_n = q <1$,

$a_n\ge 0$.

Then there is a $n_0$ such that

for $n \ge n_0:$

$a_{n+1}/a_n < p < 1$ , $0<q<p<1$, or

$a_{n+1} \lt p a_n $.

Implies:

For $n \ge  n_0:$

$a_n < a_{n_0} p^{(n-n_0)}.$

1) Monotonically decreasing , lower bound 0, hence convergent.

2) Limit is ?

Comment: Yes, right now it's easy. Thank you

Comment: W should the equality $a_n = a_0q^n$ be true?

Comment: Bernard. Yo are right. Thanks. Misread as  I do sometimes.

Comment: Vitsuk. A bit mislead reading the problem.Sorry.Hope I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is twice wrong: first $\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=q$ does *not* mean that $a_{n+1}=qa_n$, even for large $n$s. Second a monotonically decreasing sequence of positive numbers indeed has a limit, but why should this limit be $0$? Just think of $a_n=10^6+\dfrac1n$, for instance.

**Hint:**

Show that, for any $k>q$, $\;a_{n+1}<ka_n$ for all large enough $n$. Deduce that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded from above, if $n$ is large enough, by a geometric series with ratio $k$, which you may choose  less than $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using series. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = q <1$ shows the series $\sum a_n$ is converges so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, monotonically decreasing doesn't mean convergence to zero.

For simple problems like that, I'd recommend going back to the goold old epsilon:

Assume $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = q$ such as $q >= 0$ and $q < 1$.

Let's pick $p = \frac{q+1}{2}$.

By limits definitions:

$\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such as $\forall n \ge N, \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le p$

Then:
$\forall m \ge N, a_m \le a_N p^{m-N}$

Can you conclude from that?